# aggregate and sum daily data to month in python

Tags: python, json, arraylist, grouping, aggregate

I have a two-dimensional list in Python that contains the epoch seconds for a day and a respective value. I need to aggregate this list into a json array of months and the sum of all the respective daily values.

The python list looks like this:

```
array = [[1230768000000, 23], [1244073599000, 5], [1269206974000, 8], [1291908086000, 23]...]
```

I need to jsonify it into a json array that looks like this:

```
[{key:'2009-01',value:28},{key:'2009-02',value:324} ... ]
```

I've tried the following code but it doesn't quite output exactly what I need.

```
month_aggregate = defaultdict(list)
for [d,v] in array:
  truncated = int(str(d)[:-3])
  year_month = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(truncated).date().isoformat()[:-3]
  month_aggregate[year_month].append(v)

>> {'2011-08': [559, 601, 545, 578], '2011-09': [572, 491, 595], ... }
```

Tips much appreciated

Comment: @ZJS I agree... importing panda and creating a dataframe for such a small one time task seemed like overkill though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
array = [[1230768000000, 23], [1244073599000, 5], [1269206974000, 8], [1291908086000, 23]]

month_aggregate = dict()
for [d,v] in array:
    truncated = int(str(d)[:-3])    
    year_month = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(truncated).date().isoformat()[:-3]
    # If the entry was not present previously create one with the current value v
    if not month_aggregate.has_key(year_month):
        month_aggregate[year_month] = v
    else:
        # Otherwise add the value to the previous entry
        month_aggregate[year_month] += v

# Create a JSON Array from the month_aggregate dictionary
month_aggregate_json_list = [ {'value':v, 'key':k} for k, v in month_aggregate.iteritems() ]
print month_aggregate_json_list
```

Gives this

```
[{'key': '2009-01', 'value': 23}, {'key': '2009-06', 'value': 5}, {'key': '2010-03', 'value': 8}, {'key': '2010-12', 'value': 23}]
```

Comment: nice answer... and then I should be able to jsonify() that final list in Flask?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Counter from collections. I found it the other day and it's been useful a bunch.

```
from collections import Counter
month_aggregate = Counter()
for [d,v] in array:
    truncated = int(str(d)[:-3])
    year_month = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(truncated).date().isoformat()[:-3]
    month_aggregate[year_month] += v
    [{"key":k, "value":v} for k,v in month_aggregate.items()]
```

gives:

```
[{'key': '2009-06', 'value': 5},
 {'key': '2010-03', 'value': 8},
 {'key': '2010-12', 'value': 23},
 {'key': '2009-01', 'value': 23}]
```

Comment: this was close... i had never heard of Counter() before but just now started playing with it and do like it.. .if you had flushed out the answer by iterating through month_aggregate.items to create a json array I would've given it to you

Answer (score 0):

The following answer utilizes the Counter class from Collections, which is probably the best/fastest data type for this problem

```
from operator import add
from collections import Counter

l = [[1230768000000, 23], [1244073599000, 5], [1269206974000, 8], [1291908086000, 23]]

getDate = lambda x: time.strftime('%Y-%m', time.localtime(x/1000))
counter = reduce(add,[Counter({getDate(key):val}) for key,val in l])
```

At this point you have a nice Collections data type with all your information if you really want to convert it back into json just use list comprehension...

```
json = [{'key':k,'value':v} for k,v in counter.iteritems()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in itertools is meant for. Group by returns iterators that will use a given function to determine the group that an item that belongs to and return an iterator for each group that iterates over all items in that group.

```
from itertools import groupby
from time import gmtime, strftime 
# gmtime uses the UTC timezone, use the function localtime if preferred

def get_year_month_from_datum((millis, _value)):
    return strftime("%Y-%m", gmtime(millis / 1000))

aggregate = {key: sum(value for _time, value in values)
    for key, values in groupby(array, get_year_month_from_datum)} 

json_aggr = [{"key": key, "value": sum(value for _time, value in values)} 
    for key, values in groupby(array, get_year_month_from_datum)]
```

The `groupby` function assumes the input array is already sorted according to grouping value, if not then grouping by `sorted(array)` instead of `array` will work.